# Images as planes (Video texture) not working with cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, video

I am coming from Maya, and this is my first project in Blender (Maya  is too expensive).

I was using images as texture to use an mp4 file. So I got my node setup, it would refresh the texture when I am previewing it in the viewport(by dragging the timeline) but while rendering it out, It won't update the texture. Perhaps it works fine with eevee, its just cycles, but then again, eevee renders bad and cycles doesn't update .

If anyone knows how to make these work with cycles, Please let me know.

Evee renderer

[image]

Here is my node setup (I don't think rest of the node setup is related to this problem, so I didn't include it as there is no space to include that).

[image: Here is my node setup (I don't think rest of the node setup is related to this problem in any way so I didn't include it as there is no space to include that)]

[image]

[image]

Comment: From what I see on screens and tested even with binding cameras, it works all fine, so if no one here, please attach your blend just with screen object ( if the issue persists) via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: @vklidu I have embedded the blend file. Note how it renders just fine while using evee renderer but it does not update while using cycles renderer

Comment: Attached file works for me (Cycles or Eevee). I had to attach my anim.mp4, but I don't think it can be issue, more of that when it works for Eevee for you. Did you try the file you attached? Issue is there for you?

Comment: I actually did try rendering it out, it did not work, and I even created a new file, Made a plane, attached the video file and it still won't work with cycles.

Comment: Since I cant reproduce the issue hard to help. You can try to pack the video texture if it is not big, but seems to me weird it can be the case. Does it happen with another video texture as well or only with this specific?

Comment: Let me try it with another video, and Let me also try rendering it on my 2nd pc, if it does not work I will send you the whole project file. I will get back to you asap

Comment: Try open a new blend and go to File > Defaults > Load Factory probably some add-on cause the issue, still cant believe it works for one engine and not for more proved cycles? Or try my video to avoid some codec issue you use with other your videos https://www.dropbox.com/s/41cno0s8310bm37/test.mp4?dl=0

Comment: so here is an update
I had only one addon, that was for maya controls(Blender controls are too hard for me)
I restored the factory defaults, and imported your video file this time, I rendered with eeve, it works, but when I switch it up to cycles, It would render the first frame only(like before).

Comment: Try different build 2.9x ... I'm quit, I don't have more advices :) Graphic card bug??? Sorry

Comment: https://youtu.be/nPq3-6SsC7o here is whats actually happening i am using blender 2.83.5

Comment: maybe I will swtich to octane build :/

Comment: Here it is https://developer.blender.org/T79952 bug in 2.83 LTS (works in 2.9x). Since it is LTS version, should be fixed. It has high priority, confirmed, but not fixed yet.

Comment: yeah, I switched to octane edition and cycles works fine in that, anyway thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug (any version newer than 2.83.4), This is fixed in 2.90 beta and 2.91 alpha.

Thanks @vklidu for helping me out.

[developer.blender.org/T79952](http://developer.blender.org/T79952)